# Optimize this code to Parallel.ForEach or any better way in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach

I have a piece of code. How to convert this to Parallel.ForEach? I tried to use threading for code optimization. Can someone help me to get the output?

```
  List<BOUserShoutoutResponseData> result = conList.Select(con =>
            {
                List<string> totalShoutoutImages = new List<string>();
                totalShoutoutImages = ShoutoutMultipleImages(con.ShoutoutId, con.UserId, con.ShoutoutImageName, con.IsImageSync, shoutoutImages);
                return new BOUserShoutoutResponseData()
                {
                    UserName = (con.FirstName ?? string.Empty) + " " + (con.LastName ?? string.Empty),
                    UserId = (Guid)con.UserId,
                    Distacne =
                        Convert.ToDecimal(
                            Math.Round(
                                ConvertDistance.DistanceTo(Convert.ToDouble(request.UserLatitude),
                                    Convert.ToDouble(request.UserLongitude), Convert.ToDouble(con.UserLatitude),
                                    Convert.ToDouble(con.UserLongitude), request.DistanceType[0]), 12)),
                    DistacneTemp = Convert.ToDecimal(con.Distance),
                    ShoutoutLatitude = Convert.ToString(con.ShoutoutLatitude),
                    ShoutoutLongitude = Convert.ToString(con.ShoutoutLongitude),
                    ShoutoutTypeId = con.ShoutoutTypeId ?? 0,
                    ShoutoutType = con.ShoutoutType ?? string.Empty,
                    PostTypeId = con.PostTypeId ?? 0,
                    PostType = con.PostTypeName ?? string.Empty,
                    Description = con.Description ?? string.Empty,
                    TotalLike = (int)con.TotalLike,
                    Url = con.Url ?? string.Empty,
                    PlaceId = con.PlaceId ?? string.Empty,
                    AddressComponents = 
                    GetAddressComponentOfShoutout((long)con.ShoutoutId),
                    UserSmallImagePath =
                        string.IsNullOrEmpty(con.ImageName)
                            ? string.Empty
                            : GetUserImagePath(con.ImageName + "--S", 
    (bool)con.IsProfileImageSync),
GetShoutoutImagePath(con.UserId.ToString(), con.ShoutoutImageName + "--M", 
(bool)con.IsImageSync),
                    ShoutoutImages = totalShoutoutImages ?? null                        
        return result;
```

Comment: I'll give you a clue, `Select` just does a foreach under the hood. Apart from that this shows a [distinct lack of effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I'd also suggest you're wary of the run in parallel to makez the codez fastr approach. This may or may not be true depending on your implementation and lot's of other variables

Comment: What are `conList` and `ShoutoutMultipleImages` and what is taking so long that you need to use parallelism? `totalShoutoutImages` is never used in this code

Comment: totalShoutoutImages is not being used so just remove, also why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add `AsParallel()` and turn *Linq* into *Parallel Linq*?

```
List<BOUserShoutoutResponseData> result = conList
  .AsParallel() // Same Linq but doing in parallel
//.AsOrdered()  // uncomment if you want to preserve items' order
  .Select(//TODO: check totalShoutoutImages usage
          con => new BOUserShoutoutResponseData() { 
            UserName     = string.Join(" ", con.FirstName, con.LastName),
            PostTypeId   = con.PostTypeId ?? 0,
            PostType     = con.PostTypeName ?? string.Empty,
            Description  = con.Description ?? string.Empty,
            TotalLike    = (int)con.TotalLike,
            TotalComment = (int)con.TotalComment
            ... 
          })
  .ToList();

return result;
```

Then you may want to tune the query with `WithDegreeOfParallelism(...)`, `WithMergeOptions(...)` etc. options.

Comment: This may or may not help. `totalShoutoutImages` is never used. Using parallelism for a simple projection sounds strange. Perhaps `ShoutoutMultipleImages` has side-effects?